# ¿Cómo migrar un proyecto de struts 1.1 a alguna versión del 2?

Tags: java, struts, struts2, migration

Buen día, compañeros. Se me pidió migrar un sistema creado en struts 1.1 (struts.jar > META-INF > MANIFEST según esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021995/how-to-find-the-struts-version-being-used-in-a-project) hacia la versión 2.5.10.1 (que parece ser la última).

Según la página oficial de struts apache https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-tools.html hay una herramienta para lograr la migración pero no logro encontrarla, ¿o es que entendí mal y no es un software lo que se describe ahí?

Creo que primero hay que migrar de 1.x a 2 y ya después a la versión 2.x que se necesita ¿no?

La verdad acabo de comenzar a trabajar con Struts y apenas y tengo conocimientos de él

Answer (score 1):

En la descarga de struts2 vienen estas rutas donde vienen tutoriales de como hacerlo:

struts-2.5.5-all/struts-2.5.5/docs/docs/struts-1-plugin.html

struts-2.5.5-all/struts-2.5.5/docs/docs/struts-1-solutions.html

En la pagina que colocas habla de 3 partes para convertir las secciones de struts 1 a struts 2.

1. Dice que uses XSLT para convertir el struts-config.xml a struts.xml.
   Si no sabes XSL aqui estas en un lio.
2. Convertir las clases struts1 Action a las clases session-aware struts2 Action.
3. Convertir los struts1 JSPs to struts2 JSPs (no-trivial)

Pero a mi me parece que esto es un guía de como hacerlo y no entendí que haya alguna herramienta que lo convierta.

Si no sabes al menos como funciona struts1 creo que deberías empezar por ahí, por entender como funciona, y después struts2 tiene clases y configuraciones para utilizar lo que se usa en struts1, precisamente para estas migraciones.

Pero todo esto lleva tiempo, y si tienes prisa yo te recomendaría buscar algún curso que puedas tomar de ambos frameworks.